# How can I kill any/all running chef processes before kicking off a new chef process?

Tags: chef-infra

I am new to chef and have an issue where after a job is cancelled, chef processes are not getting killed properly. On retries, this causes the step to hang. How can I check for *any* running processes and kill them before beginning the retry?

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not related to chef. but you can chef `ps aux | grep chef` this will list down all the current running processes and print only the ones that includes `chef` in them.